# Which XQuery engine JBoss AS 7 supports?

Tags: jboss, xquery

I am working on AVOS to camunda migration project and getting issues while using existing XQuery files in JBoss AS 7. Which engine/version of XQuery, JBoss AS 7 supports?

Comment: @davejal while the question could be better presented, I don't think your suggestions apply here : the question is more about JBoss software architecture than a XQuery implementation problem.

Comment: point taken, removed comment

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, JBoss EAP does not provide any XQuery processor. It however embeds Xalan which provides an XSLT processor.

RedHat would probably propose you to use their JBoss Fuse product to implement XQuery transformations. I've never used the product so I won't be able to give you any feedback on it.

Of course a viable alternative is adding an XQuery processor like Saxon to your application or platform yourself. If you want to deploy it to the platform instead of to each application, see the module mechanism.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for Response and details. I tried using the Saxon-HE-9.7.0-1 and also with basex-api-7.6, basex-xqj-1.2.0... but getting errors

Comment: H Aaron,Thanks for the response and details. I tried with Saxon-HE-9.7.0-1, saxon-8.7, saxon-dom-8.7 and also with basex-api-7.6,basex-xqj-1.2.0. But getting errors as "XPST0003] Library modules cannot be evaluated" , "[XQST0045] Function 'validateOrder' is in reserved namespace" , "[XQST0033] Duplicate declaration of prefix 'm"   .. Thanks

Comment: am getting the error in jboss server log as ".
[XPST0003] Empty query & [XQST0033] Duplicate declaration of prefix 'm'" for the given below examples
Ex1.xq
xquery version "3.0" encoding "utf-8";
import module namespace m= 'http://basex.org/modules/Hello' at 'Ex2.xq';
m:hello("Universe")

Ex2.xq
xquery version "3.0" encoding "utf-8";
module namespace m = 'http://basex.org/modules/Hello';
declare function m:hello($world) {
  'Hello ' || $world
};

Comment: @VENKATARAJUNANDAM I think you should post this in another question as it will probably require you to post (extract of) your XQuery code and probably has nothing to do with JBoss. As a short answer, it looks like you have problem importing XQuery libraries. Maybe Saxon is more strict than your previous Xquery processor. Please also accept my answer if it solved your immediate problem (executing XQuery in Jboss)

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thanks for response. Yes, probably it is not with jboss too. But just want to know which implementation of xquery will be supported by Camunda-Jboss-Distribution? Am trying with a basic program, but not able to proceed. Thanks in advance for suggestions and solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have any knowledge about Camunda